# Can I use a LEFT JOIN on a grouped result?

Tags: mariadb

I have the following two queries, which on their own work as expected:

```
(SELECT 
    max(ID_box_connections) AS bc1_ID_box_connections, 
    ID_boxes_from 
FROM box_connections 
GROUP BY ID_boxes_from)
```

and:

```
(SELECT 
    ID_box_connections AS bc2_ID_box_connections, 
    date AS last_connection 
FROM box_connections)
```

But as soon as I want to join those queries via a LEFT JOIN, MariaDB returns an error:

```
(
    (SELECT max(ID_box_connections) AS bc1_ID_box_connections, ID_boxes_from FROM box_connections GROUP BY ID_boxes_from)

LEFT JOIN

    (SELECT ID_box_connections AS bc2_ID_box_connections, date AS last_connection FROM box_connections)

ON bc1_ID_box_connections = bc2_ID_box_connections)
```

The returned error says:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ID_box_connections AS bc2_ID_box_connections, ' at line 3
```

Side note: The result of this query is used by another one, so I try to get along with just one database query, using several queries would be an inconvenience to work with...

Comment: What's with all the parentheses? You can't just sprinkle them around at will, they have certain meaning.

Comment: Each subquery must be assigned with unique alias. The error message points you to the absence of the alias.

Comment: Provide COMPLETE SQL code for the last query, not a part of it.